# SSRS - Can I run datasets from different datasources sequentially

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report (SSRS / SQL Server 2008 R2) where I need to access 2 datasources and each datasource has a dataset. I need the query in DataSource1-Dataset1 to run and complete before the query from DataSource2-DataSet2 starts.

Ultimately I'd like to use a result of Dataset1 as an input parameter to Dataset2. I know if there is only one datasource I can check the 'Use single transaction' in the Data Source Properties, however with 2 different datasources that didn't help. I have also tried creating a hidden parameter that has a default value based on dataset1. That worked up until dataset1 needed a parameter itself.

Any suggestions on how to set this up would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the SSRS report data explorer, the datasets are listed in order that they will be evaluated and started.  Normally they are run in parallel, but if you make a dependency between them, they will run in sequence.  Create a parameter that is sourced from dataset 1 and use that parameter in dataset 2.  This will force SSRS to complete the results in order.

Keep in mind however that this will slow down the overall presentation speed of your report.

Comment: In order to link the datasets I tried creating parameter with a default value of the field from dataset1.  Then I had dataset2 use that parameter.   That worked provided dataset1 had no input parameters.  The issue is the first dataset needs input parameters.  
I next tried the following:  
Create 2 parameters Parameter1, Paameter2.
Dataset1 selects a value (result1) and takes Parameter1 as input.  
Parameter2 is hidden with a default value of Result1 from Dataset1.  
Dataset2 uses Parameter 2.  
When I try to run/preview that I get an error "Forward dependencies are not valid"

Comment: I have also tried using the field from dataset1 as a parameter value in dataset2 but then have the error "Fields cannot be used in query parameter expressions"

Comment: Sounds like Cascading parameters.  You have to populate them in order.  If dataset1 depends on parameter1, then parameter1 must come before parameter2 in the parameter list.  You list the dependencies out.  The item (dataset or parameter) that doesn't have any external dependencies comes first.

Comment: Fixing the order worked.  thank you.  I also found adding the second dataset as a sub report also worked but reordering the parameters is alot easier.  Thanks.